# jquery ajax call getting old data when re-used

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that builds a small graph in a popup window.  The html for the link is re-used in many different links for different devices on the page.  What happens, is that when you click a graph for the first device, you get that device.  You click a button for the second device, you get that device, however, if you keep clicking away, after the third click or so, you suddenly start getting only the first device, over and over.  I think my variables are being cached in some odd way, and I don't understand:

the HTML:

```
<a class="bluebtn graphbutton ingraph" href="http://wasat/cgi-bin/rrdjson.cgi?res=3600&start=-24h&end=now-1h&uid=28.7B2562040000" data-uid="28.7B2562040000" data-name="Laundry Room Freezer"></a>
<a class="bluebtn graphbutton ingraph" href="http://wasat/cgi-bin/rrdjson.cgi?res=3600&start=-24h&end=now-1h&uid=28.F7A962040000" data-uid="28.F7A962040000" data-name="Garage Temp"></a>
```

The code in question:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.graphbutton').click(function(e) {
    var formURL = $(this).attr("href");
    var uid = $(this).data("uid");
    var name = $(this).data("name");

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: formURL,
      dataType: "json",
      cache: false,
      context: this,
      success: function(data){
      console.log("calling mkgraph with uid "+uid+" name " +name);
      make_graph(data.data, uid, name);
    },
      error: function(ts) { 
      console.log(ts.responseText); }
      });
  }); /* clickfunc */
}); /*docready */
```

What happens:

```
Click freezer:
"calling mkgraph with uid 28.7B2562040000 name Laundry Room Freezer"
Click Garage:
"calling mkgraph with uid 28.F7A962040000 name Garage Temp"
Click Garage again:
"calling mkgraph with uid 28.7B2562040000 name Laundry Room Freezer"
```

Some of these links are being manufactured by the make_graph() function.  I'm a bit worried that this is the issue, and somehow the ajax thing needs to be re-initialized after doing this?

By request, the relevant code in make_graph() that I think is causing my issue here.  Basically, I'm editing the buttons in the css popup on the fly, and I think this is creating a wierd situation where the ajax binding is bound to the old href, and not being updated, even though the link is correct in the produced html.  This is consistent with the effect where the binding only gets mangled on the third attempt.

```
$(".ingraph").each(function() {
 this.href = $(this).attr("href").replace(/uid=.*/g, 'uid=' + uid);
 this.setAttribute('data-uid' ,uid);
 if (devname.length > 0) {
   this.setAttribute('data-name', devname);
 }
});
```

EDIT: adding a long answer:

I have multiple buttons on the main page.  Each one specifies a "uid" that gets fed to rrdjson.cgi, which takes the uid and finds the data for that device, and returns it as json.   When make_graph() recieves this json data, it populates a css popup, with the graph, and edits 5 buttons so they reference that UID.  Those 5 buttons change the timescale of the graph by re-requesting the data from rrdjson.cgi.

What I am worried is happening, is that I click on the frige, it changes the uid's of the buttons inside the popup to reference the frige. Then I close that, click on the garage, it also changes the uid's and correctly shows the garage data. Then I click on one of the buttons inside the popup for the garage, and poof, I get the refrigerator again.  I suspect that ajax "remembers" the old values for $(this).attr("href") etc and passes those values to the code, rather than re-reading the contents of the HTML.  (perhaps instead of HTML, I meant DOM there, I'm a little vauge on the difference, but I suspect I meant DOM)

Maybe the answer is to somehow un-register the ajax binding to those buttons and re-register it every time make_graph() changes them?  How would I do the un-register?  .off() ?  .unbind() ?

Comment: No chance you're clicking on things fast/repeatedly enough that the async requests are coming back in a different order, right?  `mkgraph` will be called in the order that requests are returned, which is not necessarily the order of clicks or the order that requests were made.

Comment: if you think problem is `make_graph()` wouldn't it help to show what it does? Also please note if any errors are being thrown and what they are if so

Comment: would help to see make_graph()

Comment: I have added an edit, showing the relevant portion of make_graph().  I've left out the big parts where it draws a graph, and kicks up the popup.  Also, no errors.  it works "fine", just gives me data from the wrong device.

Comment: Where does `devname` comes from? Do you want to replace data-uid and data-name with values that you receive via ajax?

Comment: devname comes from the third argument to make_graph().  Basically, what make_graph() does, is get the json data, the "uid" and the "name".  It then makes a graph in a popup, and edits the buttons on the popup to point to the uid and name of the device that triggered the popup.  This way, basically, once the graph is up, you can re-submit the ajax query with different href parameters, and see the graph in different resolutions.

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand that all together. You have some buttons. One button per device. If you click button A for device A, you get a popup with a nice graph for device A. And then you want to change button A to an other URL, so that on the next click you get other data for the graph. The logic for the decission wich data you'll get resists in http://wasat/cgi-bin/rrdjson.cgi Is that right so far? Is your system something like show data in pagination mode? 1. click data of today, 2. click data of yesterday etc ?

Comment: Hrmm.. close.  Let me try to explain better.

Answer (score 2):

After much gnashing of teeth, and google, I have answered my own question.

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-data-caching-of-data-attributes

Turns out, jquery caches "data" types, but not attr types.  So when I do:

uid = $(this).data("uid");

vs

uid = $(this).attr("data-uid");

I get wildly different results.  I guess the moral of the story is that .data is super evil.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you add a random value to your url like

```
var formURL = $(this).attr("href")+"?rv="+Math.random();
```

you'll force the ajax call to reload the URL. You can use the cache property (set it to false) JQuery will load the data again, but any proxy may send a cached version.

(Please check that there are no other attributes set in the url, otherwise set `"&rv="+Math.random();` (& instead of ?) use

```
var formURL = $(this).attr("href");
formURL + (formURL.indexOf("?") > 0 ? "&rv=" : "?rv=" )+ Math.random();
```

Your problem should not have something to do with make_graph() as uid and name depend on $('.graphbutton')

(if not make_graph(), or some other function, changes the attributes of your buttons)

Comment: Okay, as you show in the edit of your question, make_graph() manipulates the buttons. I'll start a fiddle ...